# Le mot « avoir », peut-il signifier « manger » ?

Tags: sens, alimentation

En français, peut-on dire « J'ai eu de la pizza » pour vouloir dire « J'ai pris de la pizza » ou « J'ai mangé de la pizza » comme on peut le faire en anglais ?

(En anglais, en général, « I had some pizza » veut dire « J'ai mangé de la pizza ».)

Answer (score 16):

On peut dire tout ça, mais le sens n'est pas exactement identique :

> **J'ai mangé de la pizza** : Pas de doute sur la consommation.
>
> **J'ai eu de la pizza** : On m'a donné de la pizza, je n'avais peut-être pas le choix (ex: j'ai eu de la pizza à la cantine). Je ne l'ai peut-être pas mangée si je n'avais pas faim ou si je n'aime pas ça.
>
> **J'ai pris de la pizza** : J'ai choisi de la pizza car j'avais le choix. Je l'ai probablement mangée mais il est aussi possible que j'en ai pris pour plus tard (ex: j'ai pris de la pizza surgelée au supermarché) ou pour en donner à quelqu'un d'autre (ex: j'ai pris de la pizza pour les enfants).

Pour répondre à la question posée, ***I had some pizza*** ne se traduit pas par « **J'ai eu de la pizza** » mais par « **J'ai mangé de la pizza** ». De la même manière, ***I had a beer*** se traduit par « **J'ai bu ou j'ai pris une bière** », jamais par « **j'ai eu une bière** ».

Comment: Cannot "J'ai eu de la pizza" mean that I *chose* to eat pizza? Example: "T'as faim, Charles ?" "Non, je viens de rentrer du resto. J'ai eu de la pizza."

Comment: @cccg03 *J'ai eu de la pizza* doesn't imply the pizza was chosen, even if it that was probably the case.

Comment: I only ask because the way you explained it in French made it sound like saying "J'ai eu de la pizza" means that you *don't ever* had a choice.

Comment: @cccg03 Not having a choice doesn't mean you didn't eat or enjoyed the meal, just like you would say *j'ai eu des chocolats* for Christmas in case they were offered to you while on the other hand you would say *j'ai pris des chocolats* either if you buy and bring some chocolates to the party or you pick some chocolates that were available to everyone, among other things.

Comment: On entend aussi souvent "Je me suis pris une pizza" ou bien "ce midi, je me suis pris un sandwich". Cette formulation (se prendre qch à manger) demeure plus familière.

Comment: @Nomaru oui, voire même "Je me suis mangé une pizza".

Comment: C'est juste, mais quand on commande on évitera p.-ê. de dire un truc comme _je te prendrais une pizza_ ; à mon avis mieux vaut _je vais prendre une pizza_, mais tout ça n'a rien à voir avec la question. En fait la réponse est directement _non_, et donc la langue française reste un incontournable en français.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax "la langue française reste un incontournable en français" : On ne saurait mieux dire ! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

En anglais, "I got a pizza" ne veut pas necessairement dire que j'ai mangé une pizza, mais en francais, on peut suivre le même contexte pour dire "J'ai eu une pizza" qui est moins lourde que "J'ai eu de la pizza". A ma connaisance, "J'ai pris de la pizza" ne se dit pas.

Comment: Personnellement, j'ai déjà entendu "J'ai pris de la pizza" au même titre que "j'ai pris du gratin/chou fleur/riz...." - sous entendu un choix de repas au restaurant, ce qu'on a _mangé_ au restaurant

Comment: En anglais je veux dire « I had some pizza » ou « I had a pizza ». Par exemple si quelqu'un vous demande « Are you hungry? » Vous pourriez répondre avec « No, I had some pizza ». Ça veut dire « No, I ate some pizza ».

Answer (score 1):

J'ai eu de la pizza semble plus à un niveau de possession. Comme par exemple j'ai eu un vélo.

Answer (score 1):

> J'ai eu de la pizza.
>   I got pizza.

Ceci veut dire que tu as eu de la pizza, on ne sait pas ce que tu en as fait.

---

> J'ai pris de la pizza.
>   I got myself pizza.

Cette phrase veut dire que tu as choisi d'avoir de la pizza, rien ne t'es imposé.

---

> J'ai mangé de la pizza.
>   I ate pizza.

Ceci signifie que tu as mangé de la pizza.

Answer (score 0):

Dans la phrase "**j'ai eu de la pizza**", le sous-entendu contextuel est "**J'ai eu de la pizza à manger**", mais bien sûr cette phrase est trop lourde. De plus le fait de dire "**de là**" et non pas "**une**" accentue ce sous-entendu.

En anglais, on peut traduire ça tout simplement par "**I had a pizza (to eat)**", là encore, le "**to eat**" est sous-entendu. Si on dit par contre "**I got a pizza**", le sens paraît plus ambigu, car on peut en avoir fait autre chose.

Aussi, "**j'ai eu de la pizza**" est sûrement la réponse à la question "**Qu'as-tu mangé ce midi ?**" ou **"Qu-as tu eu à manger ce midi ?"** et donc le sens ne fait aucun doute.

En effet, le fait de dire "**J'ai pris de la (ou une) pizza**" indique un degré de choix supplémentaire, alors que la phrase de l'OP ne nous apporte pas de précision sur le choix éventuel.

Dans la plupart des cas de ce contexte (parlant de nourriture), cette phrase sera comprise comme le fait d'avoir mangé une pizza. Dans le cas contraire, une précision est faite, mais pas dans le cas où le sens paraît évident.

**TL:DR** En conclusion, si on suit à la règle la théorie, on peut en effet avoir un doute. En pratique, tout le monde comprend la même chose dans le cas où l'on parle de nourriture.